gitlab-ce does not show test coverage on the project badged, always 'unkown'
I'm trying to make the coverage badged work on gitlab-ce, but no success so far.
My badge still unknown:

The badged configuration is:

I tried with both job-related URL and without specifying the job. It didn't do any good.
The job works fine and it reports the coverage percentage:

The gitlab-ce gets the percentage into the merge request, with the test summary:

The job is:
run_tests_job:
  stage: testing

  tags:
    - prepare_test

  environment: staging

  needs: ["install_dependencies_job"]

  rules:
      - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev"'
        when: on_success
      - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "hml"'
        when: on_success

  script:
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - python3.12 -m pytest --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov=. --cov-fail-under=70 --cov-report term-missing --cov-report xml:coverage_detailed.xml --junitxml=coverage.xml
    - echo "Running tests"
    - echo "Current package passed all tests successfully"

  coverage: '/Total coverage:.*?(\d+.\d+)/'

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage.xml
      - coverage_detailed.xml
    reports:
      junit: coverage.xml
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage_detailed.xml


  cache:
    key: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
    paths:
      - venv/
    policy: pull

  allow_failure: false

I tried a lot of tips and even chatgpt 4, without any success.
Any advices? Thanks in advance!!!

Have you merged this change and have it produce at least one report on the default branch of your project?

Yes, I did that several times, no changes on the badge, despite everything else being updated.
